# issue installing postgis on mac osx

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, geos

I am installing postgis on mac osx and getting this error

```
configure: error: could not find proj_api.h - you may need to specify the directory of a PROJ.4 installation using --with-projdir
```

I have installed geos following this command.

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.1.1.tar.bz2
tar xfj geos-3.1.1.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.1.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

I am installing postgis following these commands

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
tar xfz postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.0.6
./configure
```

I get error after the last line. I am new to mac I will be really very thankful if someone helps.I am not able to find this proj_api.h or anything as listed in the error

Comment: If you installed Postgres using the likes of Homebrew or Darwinports, you need to correctly set the include path.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy
Could you please tell me how and where

Comment: Probably `./configure --with-pgconfig=/path/to/bin/pg_config`

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy
I did it but still giving the same error

Comment: I'm afraid I've no idea then. Googling "proj_api.h postgis" yields a bunch of results. Have you checked them?